# get list of modified configs

Tags: apt

How can I get a list of all modified configs (in `/etc`), i.e. configs which differ from the originally installed version, i.e. configs where an update would ask about how to proceed with the locally modified config?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/90400/how-to-check-for-modified-config-files-on-a-debian-system

Comment: Btw., who downvotes this? It would have been helpful to find such question at the top of Google results. Thanks anyway muru, that was very helpful.

Comment: you're welcome. I find it surprising it's answered on SF and not here or on [unix.se]. (Well, only on U&L now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the link by muru [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/90400/how-to-check-for-modified-config-files-on-a-debian-system):

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Conffiles}\n' '*' | awk 'OFS="  "{print $2,$1}' | LANG=C md5sum -c 2>/dev/null | awk -F': ' '$2 !~ /OK$/{print $1}'
```

Or:

```
debsums -ce
```

Or also helpful:

```
find /etc/ -name "*.dpkg-*"
```