# How can I get a list of files that I modified/added in /etc and other paths outside of the home folder?

Tags: upgrade, configuration, etc

Over the years, I've been making tweaks to my Ubuntu system, such as adding files to /etc, to customize it.  I now want to do a fresh re-installation of Ubuntu, and I want to capture all of these changes I've made and re-create them (by hand if necessary) in the new system.  Unfortunately, I haven't been keeping track so I can't remember what most of them are.

Is there a way to search through the rootfs and list all files that were created or edited manually by me?

P.S. this question is similar to [get list of modified configs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564265/get-list-of-modified-configs) but covers every change, not just ones that would be captured by dpkg.

Comment: Unless you set some sort of tracking  in place beforehand, nope

Comment: It is possible with `dpkg -V` and similar options, and several other dpkg tools, to generate a list of edited config files and installed files and by process of elimination, files that were added.   But this is a tedious and error prone process.  There's nothing to just generate a list.

Comment: As muru said, it is much easier to set up tracking (like git) in place beforehand.

Comment: You could mount your original installation `.iso` (or download a new copy of it), and `diff` the directories (`man diff`) to get a list of everything that's changed, created, or deleted on your system. What you've changed is a subset of this list.

Comment: The original ISO has packed deb files on it rather than the installed files, and does not include any subsequent updates.  A diff is going to be almost all false positives and false negatives with very little in common with the final installation, I can't really see how that is very helpful.  `dpkg -V` would give much better information than anything from the original ISO.